# Using JQuery functions on HTML produced by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML page that is generated by JavaScript (JQuery). It makes use of JQGrid. This is [the source](http://pastebin.com/Xz28UY7z) of the page.

I attempt to change one of the widths and check its width like so:

```
var width = window.screen.availWidth; //1280
$('#gbox_grid').css('width', width);
alert($('#gbox_grid').width()); //alerts a null
```

But the alert returns a null? The ID is correct and the element is there (via Firbug). I have done this inside document ready as well.

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: What happens when you set it via `.width()`? Like this: `$('#gbox_grid').width(width))`

Comment: If I wait for the page to load and data to appear in the grid and then turn my above code to a function and run it via a click it works. Maybe I need to wait for the AJAX request? But its only data? Maybe it renders after the data is received and the elements become available then rather than on ready.

Comment: I have tried the same code given by you.Its working fine at my end.You might be missing something in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, *yes*, you need to run this **after your AJAX call loads the element** (in your `success` or `complete` callback), otherwise it won't be there for the selector to find.

So this:

```
$('#gbox_grid')
```

won't find any elements to run [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on (or get [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) on either).  Also, you can use [`.width(newWidth)`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to set the width as well, like this:

```
$('#gbox_grid').width(width);
```

Comment: exactly, I have just used the loadComplete event.